# Update redux store with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an application required to run API calls every 3 seconds. I used `useInterval` to call API, every 3 seconds I received the API result. When I update from redux, something went wrong with `useInterval`.

**UseInterval**

```
export default function useInterval(callback, delay, immediate = true) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      async function tick() {
        await savedCallback.current();
      }
      if (delay !== null) {
        if (immediate) {
          await tick();
        }
        let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
      }
    })(); 
  }, [delay]);
}
```

**Main**

```
const enhance = connect(
  (state, ownProps) => ({
    modal: state.modal[ownProps.id]
  }),
  { updateFromRedux }
);
const container = ({ id, modal, updateFromRedux }) => {
    useInterval(() => {
        # -----> This scope of codes went wrong when updateFromRedux is called <-----
        let modalId = modal["id"]
        return fetch(`https://api-url.com/${modalId}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    updateFromRedux(id, result)
                }
            )
    }, 3000)
})
export default enhance(container);
```

**Redux**

```
export const updateFromRedux = (id, details) => ({
  type: UPDATE_DETAILS,
  payload: { id, details }
});
```

**Problem**

> The modalId produces an inconsistent output such as undefined inside useInterval after updateFromRedux redux method is called.

Comment: Please provide more details on what went wrong.

Comment: @FábioBatista I updated my answer, the modalId was undefined after updateFromRedux was called.

Comment: From your description, the error should be on your reducer. Please add its code.

Comment: Your `useEffect` call looks wrong to me. The function you pass to it should return nothing or a cleanup function, but it is currently returning a promise to a cleanup function. I'm not sure the hooks API will call your cleanup code (the `clearInterval`).